# Using the last line of a paragraph to start a new paragraph aligned to the right

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

Is it possible to define a command such that the paragraph that follows is right-aligned and its first line starts in the last line of the previous paragraph (which is justified)? Eventually, to have a minimum of horizontal blank space between the two paragraphs as the argument of that command.

**Edit:** The output should be like this (except for the red color):
[image: output example]

Comment: Could you please add a skwtch of the desired output to your question? Currently, I find it very hard to imagine how which line of text should be aligned and where the paragraphs start/end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

{
% make sure there is space on the last line
\parfillskip=.5\textwidth plus .3\textwidth
\lipsum[1]

}

\vspace{\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax}

{\raggedleft
% make sure there is space on the first line
\noindent\hspace*{\dimexpr.5\textwidth+2em}%
\lipsum[2]

}

\end{document}
```